# The `PRI` column of `ps` is inconsistent with man pages

Tags: linux, ps, man, nice

**UPDATE:** My undestanding was correct and the man page of `ps` has been updated to now state the following for the PRI column: "priority of the process.  Higher number means higher priority."

---

I've been trying to understand how scheduling priorities work in linux.
Here's what I've got:

- The kernel uses a priority value for each process which ranges from 0 to 139. The lower the number, the more priority the process has.
- Priority values from 0 to 99 are reserved, all user space processes have a priority from 100 to 139.
- Linux provides the `nice` interface which is the priority exposed to and modifiable by the user. The `nice` value ranges from -20 to 19, and maps to priorities 100 to 139. As with the priority value, the lower the `nice` value, the more priority the process has.

My question now is: **What does the PRI column of `ps` indicate?**

The man page of `ps` says:

> ```
>    pri         PRI       priority of the process.  Higher number means 
>                          lower priority.
> ```

But the value ranges from 0 to 39, and I empirically determined it is equal to `19 - nice`.

It is impossible, given the relationship, that both `nice` and the priority shown in the `PRI` column satisfy "higher number means lower priority".

What am I missing?

---

Example showing this behaviour:

```
root@kali:~# ps -ao pid,comm,pri,nice
  PID COMMAND         PRI  NI
 6153 cat              19   0
 (···)
root@kali:~# renice -n -10 -p 6153
6153 (process ID) old priority 0, new priority -10
root@kali:~# ps -ao pid,comm,pri,nice
  PID COMMAND         PRI  NI
 6153 cat              29 -10
 (···)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `PRI` from `ps -o pri` is `39 - priority`, where `priority` is the 18th field from `/proc/PID/stat`.

If you want the unmangled field from `proc/PID/stat`, you can get it with `ps -o priority`.

If you want the **real priority**, you can obtain it with `ps -o pri_baz`.

Other interesting manglings of that value could be obtained with `ps -o pri_foo`, `ps -o pri_bar` and `ps -o opri`.

I kid you not. You can look at the source [here](https://github.com/mmalecki/procps/blob/fe4c4a7314f32907b9f558ad0d8b8d0ff1cc76be/ps/output.c#L593).

Note about `/proc/PID/stat`:

The priority field (18th) in `/proc/PID/stat` is set by the kernel in [`fs/proc/array.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/1ce80e0fe98e72af4125f47c65b0bc01b60a7feb/fs/proc/array.c#L522) to `task_struct->prio - 100` (via [`task_prio()`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/1ce80e0fe98e72af4125f47c65b0bc01b60a7feb/kernel/sched/core.c#L3969); [`MAX_RT_PRIO`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/1ce80e0fe98e72af4125f47c65b0bc01b60a7feb/include/linux/sched/prio.h#L22) is defined as `100`).

Comment: Thank you! Its quite interesting that there are so many different manglings of the priority value. This still doesn't answer why the manual wrongly states the meaning of PRI, though... it should read "lower number means lower priority", given that it's 39 - priority.

Comment: I think that you should submit a bug report -- maybe to the effect of changing the standard format specifier for `PRI` from `pri` to `priority`, since that's the one that gets the value exposed by the kernel to userland.